# Why hamcrest is there in my class path?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, junit, hamcrest

I have integrated gradle with intellij and I cant seem to figure out that why hamcrest library is in my classpath even though it is not listed in the build.gradle.

[image]

Comment: I suggest looking at http://google.github.io/truth/comparison. You may find the AssertJ syntax to be more "aesthetically satisfying" than Hamcrest's. It is additional dependency, but it is only for testCompile, so it should not matter much.

Answer (score 2):

Because `junit:junit:4.12` brings it in as its transitive dependency. You can see this by running

```
./gradlew dependencies
```

Here is a relevant section from the jUnit documentation

> There is nothing extra that needs to be done in order to use a specific artifact of Hamcrest. In the past, there were two JUnit Maven artifacts: junit:junit and junit:junit-dep, where the latter version did not include a bundled copy of org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core and instead declared a transitive dependency on Hamcrest. In order to be more Maven-like, starting in version 4.11, there is only the junit:junit artifact which uses a transitive dependency on hamcrest-core.
>
> https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Use-with-Gradle